# How can children scream so loud and so long?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, human-physiology, children

Recently I saw a small baby shrieking extremely loudly (my ears hurt) for at least 4 minutes .

How is it possible? If I yelled so loudly, I would be defeated by throat ache after less than a minute. I know that heavy metal vocalists are capable of such feats, but it takes them a lot of practice.

So how can children yell so loudly for so long? Do they ignore pain? Does the pain cause the feedback loop of discomfort->yelling->more discomfort->more yelling? Or do they have vocal chords of titanium?

I tried google search, but answers are generally "why do children scream", not "how can they scream".

Comment: 4 minutes are not long,fb suporters can keep it going for 45 min.

Comment: @trond screaming and crying is a bit more physically strenuous than singing football songs, no?

Comment: I seem to remember that this question — which seems to me rhetorical — has been asked on this list before (and in life by countless parents including myself). I suspect that your real question is how to stop it, in which case I believe there is a Parenting SE. Or Doctor Spock. From memory, you let them scream themselves out.

Comment: Children are more energetic than you. Is it so surprising that this also applies to screaming? Square cube law is also probably involved.

Comment: @David this isn't a rhetorical question. I don't care how to stop crying baby. I don't have one. I'm just surprised it can go for so long and so loud.

Comment: If not rhetorical, your question seems to me to address something that has not struck others as enough of a problem to investigate.